# How to get the value of cell in dynamic table when a link is clicked using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the respective customer ID when I click on respective link in the table. I am unable to get the value of cluster ID in the for loop.

I used jQuery to create a dynamic table and simple HTML:

[image]

As you can see, in that image, if I click on the Start button it should show me first cluster ID in an alert. Here's the code that I'm having issues with:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').attr({
        class: ["class1", "class2", "class3"].join(' ')
    }).appendTo(mytable);
    var clusterid = "cluster" + i;


    $('<td><span align="center" valign="middle" id="clustr"></span></td>').text(clusterid).appendTo(row);
    $('<td><span align="center" valign="middle"></span></td>').text(sizen).appendTo(row);
    $('<td><span align="center" valign="middle"></span></td>').text(status).appendTo(row);
    $('<td><span align="center" valign="middle"></span></td>').text(type).appendTo(row);
    $('<td><span align="center" valign="middle"></span></td>').text(startdate).appendTo(row);
    $('<td><span align="center" valign="middle"></span></td>').html("<u><a target='_blank' href='" + url + "'>view hdfs</a><br><a href>view jobtracker</a><br><a href>view tasktracker</a></u>").appendTo(row);
    $('<td><span align="center" valign="middle" class="clickclass"></span></td>').html('<a href="#" id="anc" role="button"  class="btn btn-info">start</a>').appendTo(row);
    console.log("TTTTT:" + mytable.html());
    mytable.appendTo("#box");


    //alert(id);
} //for
$(function () {

    $('.btn').on('click', function () {
        var button = $(this);
        //alert(button);
        var parentTd = button.parent('td');
        //alert(parentTd);
        var parentTr = parentTd.parent('tr');
        //alert(parentTr);
        //alert(clusterid);
        var nombre = parentTr.find('td #clustr').html();
        // alert($row.find('td:eq(1)').html());
        alert(nombre);
    });

});
```

And here's my full HTML code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.css"></link>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="styles/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="styles/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#sample").prepend(
                "<div style='color:#6495ED' id='totinsinfo'> <center><h2>Cluster Information</h2></center> </div>");
            mytable = $('<table id="s"  border="2" style="width:947px;"><th bgcolor="#00BFFF"><h4>Cluster_Id</h4></th><th bgcolor="#00BFFF"><h4>Size(Nodes)</h4></th><th bgcolor="#00BFFF"><h4>Status</h4></th><th bgcolor="#00BFFF"><h4>Type</h4></th><th bgcolor="#00BFFF"><h4>Start_Date</h4></th><th bgcolor="#00BFFF"><h4>Clusterlinks</h4></th><th bgcolor="#00BFFF"><h4>Action</h4></th></table>').attr({
                id: "basicTable"
            });
            var i = 1;
            var sizen = "null";
            var startdate = "null";
            var status = "null";
            var type = "null";
            var url = "null";

            for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                var row = $('<tr></tr>').attr({
                    class: ["class1", "class2", "class3"].join(' ')
                }).appendTo(mytable);
                var clusterid = "cluster" + i;


                $('<td><span align="center" valign="middle" id="clustr"></span></td>').text(clusterid).appendTo(row);
                $('<td><span align="center" valign="middle"></span></td>').text(sizen).appendTo(row);
                $('<td><span align="center" valign="middle"></span></td>').text(status).appendTo(row);
                $('<td><span align="center" valign="middle"></span></td>').text(type).appendTo(row);
                $('<td><span align="center" valign="middle"></span></td>').text(startdate).appendTo(row);
                $('<td><span align="center" valign="middle"></span></td>').html("<u><a target='_blank' href='" + url + "'>view hdfs</a><br><a href>view jobtracker</a><br><a href>view tasktracker</a></u>").appendTo(row);
                $('<td><span align="center" valign="middle" class="clickclass"></span></td>').html('<a href="#" id="anc" role="button"  class="btn btn-info">start</a>').appendTo(row);
                console.log("TTTTT:" + mytable.html());
                mytable.appendTo("#box");


                //alert(id);
            } //for
            $(function () {
                $('.btn').on('click', function () {
                    var button = $(this);
                    //alert(button);
                    var parentTd = button.parent('td');
                    //alert(parentTd);
                    var parentTr = parentTd.parent('tr');
                    //alert(parentTr);
                    //alert(clusterid);
                    var nombre = parentTr.find('td #clustr').html();
                    // alert($row.find('td:eq(1)').html());
                    alert(nombre);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="margin-top: 46px;">
    <div class="span9" id="sample">
        <div id="box" style="margin-right: -189px;"></div>
        <div class="span8" id="empty"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, you might want to check that your code formatting is correct before posting a question or an answer - it was displayed in an extremely messy manner before I fixed it. See the [help] for more info.

Comment: sorry sir,actually I posted it for first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cant clear your codeing but clearly understand u need first td value .try this

check : http://jsfiddle.net/ke7VN/

```
 $('.btn').on('click', function () {

     console.log( $(this).parent().parent().find('td:first').text());


 });
```

Comment: Plz help me to know where the data is coming when we click on the start button.plz help me..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are appending the table dynamically you need to use event delegation

```
$('#sample').on('click', '.btn', function () { ... });
```

Structure as this

```
$('static element').on('event', 'dynamic element', function(){ ... });
```

Comment: Hi, Spokey..Instead of getting clusterid I am getting "undefined" in alert box.what does it mean?Actually, I am new to Jquery.Could you help me?

Comment: Thank for responding...I had given all my code in that textbox.I don't have any separate html for this.I created table dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to get parent tr and then #clustr

```
 $('.btn').on('click', function () {
     console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('#clustr'));
 });
```

Comment: Thank u..PKolos..for responding my query.

Comment: But I have small doubt that where the data will be stored if we write   "console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('#clustr'));" this statement.

Comment: console.log is only for displaying information in browser console, not to store data.